# What is most Efficient SQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve all the 'events' of a user (given user_id) using his subscriptions.
I know this can be done using subquery but it is slow.
Please suggest the best approach to achieve it.

Here is the sqlfiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd48e3

And here is the design image:

[image]

Comment: 1) Don't use pictures for table structures (esp. ones that require a microscope); use SQL Fiddle. 2) Questions must show minimal effort; show us your attempts.

Comment: And what is the query using a subquery?  Don't be shy.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Thanks! Edited the question. Subquery is not working as inner query is returning multiple results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select * from events e left join subscriptions s on s.r_id = e.r_id where s.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If u remove the where clause you will get the events corresponding to each user

```
select e.*,s.fname
  from users s
  join routine r ON (s.user_id = r.user_id)
  join events e ON (e.r_id = r.r_id)
 where s.user_id = ?
```